# How to sum two booleans lists in python?

Tags: python, list

for example i have two lists:

```
a=[True,False,True,False]
b=[False,True,False,True]
```

I want to return this:

```
c=[a[0] and b[0],a[1] and b[1],a[2] and b[2],a[3] and b[3]]
```

so i will have

```
c=[False,False,False,False]
```

I know i can do cycle with 'For', but is it the easiest way?
I tried
    a and b
but it returns me wrong answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[List-Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip).

```
>>> a=[True,False,True,False]
>>> b=[False,True,False,True]
>>> [i and j for i, j in zip(a,b)]
[False, False, False, False]
```

The [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function takes two (or more) lists (or iterators) and takes the first one from each and puts them together, and then goes to the second and puts them together, etc. (like a zipper)

For lists that are not the same length, you need the [`izip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) package. Which will keep zipping and place a default value with the keyword `fillvalue` (defaults to `None`).